# element.find('li') doesn't match any result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `angularJS` directive that changes `li` style properties when `toState` matches the `ui-sref` value.

For some reason the `element.find('li')` brings me an empty result. Here below I paste my code:

**navbar.js**

```
navbar.directive('appNavbar', [ function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function ($state, element) {
      $state.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function (event, toState) {
        console.log(element.find('li')); // here is comming an empty value
        angular.forEach(element.find('li'), function (a, i) {
          // li css change stuff
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

**_navbar.html**

```
<app-navbar ui-view="navbar">
  <div class="nb-main">
    <ul id="list-nav" class="list-navbar">
      <li ng-include="'svg/navbar-home.svg'" ui-sref="base.home"></li>
      <li ng-include="'svg/navbar-discover.svg'" ui-sref="base.discover"></li>
      <li ng-include="'svg/navbar-discover.svg'" ui-sref="base.discover"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="nb-img line-navbar"></div>
  </div>
</app-navbar>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(element)` in the beginning of your `link` method? At first I thought your problem was because the element is just a basic `DOMElement`, but reading more of the docs (and looking at my own code), it should be a [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) object which is exactly what you want.

Comment: It outputs me the next response: `[app-navbar.ng-scope] 0: app-navbar.ng-scope length: 1 __proto__: Object [0]`. If I start looking at `childnodes` through the array, I find the `li.ng-scope`

Comment: You really shouldn't have to do this (I originally posted an answer, but then realized the documentation contradicted me), but can you try replacing `element.find('li')` with `angular.element(element).find('li')`?

Comment: after doing it, I got a response with 0 length: `N {} > __proto__: Object[0]`

Comment: Alright. Sorry to say it, but I'm out of guesses for now. From my quick tests, the next place I'd look would be making sure that [`ngInclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) (or [`ui-sref-`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)) isn't doing anything weird with the DOM. My MVP (without these params) example in JSfiddle works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/7qhzuLah/

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> **Note:** Keep in mind that this function will not find elements by tag name / CSS selector. For lookups by tag name, try instead `angular.element(document).find(...)` or `$document.find()`, or use the standard DOM APIs, e.g. `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: That's what I originally thought; but, look right above it: "All element references in Angular are always wrapped with jQuery or jqLite[...]They are never raw DOM references." (Even the [directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom) mentions that the second param is a "jqLite-wrapped element".)

Comment: doing a `angular.element(document).find('li')` in my browser console, it outputs me elements, but for any reason, it isn't happening in my directive. That makes me think there's something wrong when loading my `ui-view`.

Comment: After so much time investigating, I've realiced what caused the issue was the `ng-include` of the `li`. Removing it solved my problem. Is that any normal behavior you know about? or should I mark it as a bug? I've been reading that people suggest to use `directives` instead of `ng-include` btw.

Answer (score 1):

Since I found the answer, I'm answering myself trying to explain the behavior of what I was trying to do and how I solved it. Basically, there were 2 problems:

The first problem was related with `$stateChangeSuccess` of `$rootScope` and `ng-include`. When the directive launched its process, the `ng-include` hadn't completed its loading.

Solving the problem in this way should be thinking on `$timeout` since you have to wait until the content has loaded.

```
navbar.directive('appNavbar', [ '$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function ($state, element) {
      $timeout(function () {
        $state.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function (event, toState) {
          console.log(element.find('li')); // here is comming an empty value
          angular.forEach(element.find('li'), function (a, i) {
            // li css change stuff
          });
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

The second one was related to use `ng-include` as attribute: `<ANY ng-include="#"></ANY>` instead of element: `<ng-include src="#"></ng-include>`. Without changing anything in the `directive`, this code solves the issue:

```
<div class="nb-main">
  <ul class="list-navbar">
    <li ui-sref="base.home">
      <ng-include src="'svg/navbar-home.svg'"></ng-include>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref="base.home">
      <ng-include src="'svg/navbar-interaction.svg'"></ng-include>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref="base.home">
      <ng-include src="'svg/navbar-discover.svg'"></ng-include>
    </li>    
  </ul>
  <div class="nb-img line-navbar"></div>
</div>
```

I still have no idea about why swapping between attributes and elements makes it work or not, but this code works like a charm!

Comment: First, @DevStarlight, glad you were able to solve the issue (hopefully we were of some help). Secondly, feel free to accept your own answer so others know instantly what helped you! Finally, in regards to the two problems: 1). [`$apply` and `$digest`](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) may be a more elegant solution than `$timeout`, and 2). I bet that `ng-include` would work as an attribute -- it just probably tells Angular to replace the element which caused `element.find()` to work incorrectly.